# How to add standard Spring security to Spring Boot Admin (2.1.4)

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Followed reference guide to add security to spring boot admin (https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/), but upon launching app always get standard login page, which I am unable to bypass (and unsure also how to do so - where to add add login credentials etc). Would like to set up for now Spring Boot Admin with basic security.

1. Created a standard boot app with "Spring Boot Admin" and "Spring Security" dependency
2. Imported project into IDE and added @EnableAdminServer annotation to main class and ran

NOTE:

1)did NOT add anything to application.properties
 2)also tried approach of using    https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-admin , where a login page is displayed using WebSecurity config , but that causes 2 login window to appear (one as popup and second as main page)

---

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.EnableAdminServer;

@EnableAdminServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

Pom :

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.1.4.RELEASE
         
    
    com.example
    demo
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    demo
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot-admin.version>2.1.4</spring-boot-admin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Would like to have Spring Boot Admin secure by most basic spring security (using spring boot 2.x)

Answer (score 0):

> but that causes 2 login window to appear (one as popup and second as main page)

I have faced this problem and i fixed it by changing the version of `spring-boot-admin`.

You are using `2.1.4` when `2.1.6` is available.

Try changing the version numbers.